# Running test with MockWebServer always call the failure call back (Connection Exception)

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp, mockwebserver

I'm running mock web server to test REST API calls, when activity launch and start the mockWebserver and execute the API call I'm getting the connection refused,using OKHTTP v-3.10.0 & Retrofit 2.3.0

ActivityTest Code:

```
 @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<STBUpgradeActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(STBUpgradeActivity.class, false, false);

    private MockWebServer server;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        super.setUp();
        server = new MockWebServer();
        server.start();
        injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        String serverUrl = server.url("/").toString();
        EnvConfig.WEB_API_SIT = serverUrl;
    }

    @Test
    public void testPageContentIsShown() throws Exception {
        String fileName = "stb_upgrade_page_content_200.json";
        server.enqueue(new MockResponse()
                .setResponseCode(200)
                .setBody(RestServiceTestHelper.getStringFromFile(getInstrumentation().getContext(), fileName)));

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        mActivityRule.launchActivity(intent);

        onView(withId(R.id.button_upgrade)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
        onView(withText("New residential subscribers and standard install only. If Sports is a part of your package")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
```

=======
RestAPI client

```
 private Retrofit getClient() { 
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(WEB_API_HOST)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(getHttpClient())
                .build();

        return retrofit;
    }
```

[image: failure call back in debug mode]

[image: mockserver start]

Answer (score 1):

Change the setUp code to

```
 @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        super.setUp();
        server = new MockWebServer();
        server.start(8080);
        injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
    }
```

set the Retroft Base URL to

```
private Retrofit getClient() {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(getHttpClient())
                .build();

        return retrofit;
    }
```

Comment: What is injectInstrumentation?